# "Hope this email finds you" or "Hope this email find you"

Tags: greetings

Which one is correct?

*Hope this email finds you well*

With an `s` after find, or

*Hope this email find you well*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`finds`

I'm not sure I can tell you why, but definitely 'finds'.

Comment: And the subjunctive is not used after _hope_, so we also say “I hope it is…”, rather than “I hope it be…”.

Comment: It is 'finds' because it is third-person - he, she, it finds. Nothing to do with plural or singular.

Answer (score 0):

Correct one is, 
Hope this *email* **finds** you well. For third person singular subject verb takes 's' in simple present tense.